# Deployed WSDL gets its XSD restrictions removed

Tags: web-services, tomcat, wsdl, websphere, axis

I'm trying to deploy a web services using TOP-DOWN and Axis 1.4, via Eclipse's Wizard "Web Services > Generate Java Skeleton", I have a WSDL with it's schemas within. One particular complexType has restrictions for its elements (it's for input):

```
      <xsd:complexType name="InformacionClienteRequestModel">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="numRut">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="\d{9}\-[k|K|0-9]"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>          
      <xsd:element name="codSituacion">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="([ABST][AP][AP])?|([ABST][AP][AP])(,([ABST][AP][AP]))*"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="filtroCodSituacion">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:pattern value="[IE]?"/>
          </xsd:restriction>            
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>            
      <xsd:element name="pagina">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>               
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="registrosPorPagina">
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:int">
            <xsd:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xsd:maxInclusive value="50"/>
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>          
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

When it gets deployed on server (I tried both Websphere and Tomcat), this complexType ends like this:

```
<complexType name="InformacionClienteRequestModel">
<sequence>
<element name="numRut" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="codSituacion" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="filtroCodSituacion" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pagina" type="xsd:int"/>
<element name="registrosPorPagina" type="xsd:int"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
```

It obviously doesn't validate the input data via SOAP, I google'd everywhere but didn't get anything.

Any ideas?